# Can test be green from the very beginning in TDD?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd, methodology

Imagine I have function `foo()`:

```
var foo = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/a/g, '');
};
```

I have following tests for it to work:

1. `foo()` exists;
2. `foo()` strips `a`'s from string and does nothing to string without `a`'s;
3. `foo()` throws `TypeError` if given something else than string;

The problem is with test #3 — however it's green from the beginning, it's not my merit. I expect to have written something like this:

```
var foo = function(string) {
    if (typeof string !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('argument should be a string');
    }

    return string.replace(/a/g, '');
};
```

but I can't, because there is no test for it. So `foo()` really throws TypeError, but not because of argument of wrong type, but because null, undefined, number, array, boolean, regexp etc. objects given as argument don't provide `replace()` method.

I think I need this test, just because JS team may for example change `TypeError` for this particular case to something like `MissingMethodError`, but I will violate Red > Green > Refactor principle. How should I resolve this situation?

Comment: if(string && !string.replace){ throw "no replace on arg"; }

Comment: @dandavis, it's not about "how to implement this check", but "what to do if test for check if green before check is implemented".

Comment: Besides which, passing in `5` (say) would get past that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen, but it's better to avoid it.  In this case, you could have avoided it by writing your tests in a different order.

1) foo exists;

Red because of course foo doesn't exist.  Write an empty foo(); now it's green.

2) foo throws a TypeError if the argument is something other than string.

Red because foo never throws a TypeError (or anything else).  Have foo unconditionally throw a TypeError; now all tests are green.

3) foo strips out the a's.

Red because it doesn't.  Now implement; now all your tests pass, and all of them started out red.

It seems like a contrived approach, and of course it is, and it's not easy to know in advance how to write the tests to adhere to red-green-refactor.  But the more you do it, the easier it becomes.

Red-green-refactor really is important and worth trying to follow, because if a test starts out green, it may not be testing anything meaningful about the system under test.  Sometimes, as in this example, you bump up against it; you can tweak the system under test to force a red, but also try to learn from it (as you are doing by posing this question) so it goes better next time.

Comment: Well, in my particular case should I just include green test and in future avoid this, or I shouldn't?

Comment: In your case I would add the green test, change the system under test temporarily to demonstrate that the test will catch if it stops throwing the required exception, and then restore to the correct state.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but my 5 cents: you shouldn't be testing the existence of a function. You should be testing requirements. And the existence of a function is doubtably a requirement.

Comment: Yes, I came to that realization independently. No one cares about actual implementation - tests should cover user stories and necessary functionality to support those stories. Think about API endpoints, or browser tests, or anything like this.

Comment: And for TDD in particular, again, there must be some part of the contract enforced by the compiler. Having public functions in your API means this shouldn't be tested - it's assumed to exist by definition. Or that functions have particular types of arguments. Don't duplicate the job of static type checker - leverage type system to do the majority of checks during compile time. For example, use generics, strong/branded types, conditional types, dependent types, use predicates and combinators to define the type inhabitants, and so on. And nothing of this requires tests.

Comment: Grounding your tests in implementation is just a recipe for fragile tests and a recipe for refactoring disaster. Don't cover your private functions with tests, keep everything as encapsulated as possible, minimize your public API surface, and delegate doing stuff to DI/IoC or effect system (so that your code is strictly deterministic and pure), and you'll be fine.

Comment: @toriningen perfectly explained

Answer (score 0):

You could probably test that your TypeError has the proper message. Currently, it is probably not what you expect.

Eventually, you should ask yourself if it would be worth having a custom error type. Easier to test against and easier to act upon while using you function.